# Login particulars or Login credentials?

Tags: grammar, difference

Which is correct?

> What are your login credentials/particulars?

Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find "login credentials", "login info", and even "login details" to be fine. "Login particulars" sounds unnatural to me.

You can also use just "login" like in the following book:

> “June Bug, what's your login?” Amanda, who was standing mere inches away from Sarah, glanced down at the woman's cell phone. “Hold on, love,” she whispered into her own cell phone, putting her frantic husband on hold, and whispered her username and password to Sarah. — [Snow Way Out](https://books.google.com/books?id=n29rEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT30&dq=%22what%27s%20your%20login%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje1-HKm8b3AhU3jIkEHewCCMkQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%22what%27s%20your%20login%22&f=false)

It's the shortest way you could ask, though in some contexts it might just be interpreted as not including the password (probably because you shouldn't be exchanging passwords).

However, your best bet (in both technical writing and giving technical assistance) would be to ask for exactly what you want: "username and password", "API key", "email and PIN", or even "employee ID, password, and 2FA code from your texts". If you're not being specific like that, you're relying on the other person to have a level of knowledge of the system that they might not have, especially off the top of their head.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a difference. However:

The expression I have heard the most is "login details". 
"Login credentials" sounds right too. 
"Login particulars", however, is something I had never heard before reading this post.

A Google search brings in:

Over 7 million results for "your login credentials"
Over 6 million results for "your login details"
Only over 12 thousand for "your login particulars"

And here is the Ngram result: ([Ngram link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=your%20login%20particulars%2Cyour%20login%20credentials%2Cyour%20login%20details&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyour%20login%20credentials%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyour%20login%20details%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cyour%20login%20credentials%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyour%20login%20details%3B%2Cc0))

[image]

We can conclude from the above that "login credentials" and "login details" are both correct and commonly used. However, the former is rapidly declining in popularity. "Login details" seems to be the way to go.

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into that ngram. I suspect that the Google Books corpus contains only a tiny sliver of the actual use of those terms in written English, let alone spoken English.